# comma separated string to list in r

Tags: r, string, list, split

I have a comma separated string in R:-

```
"a,b,c"
```

I want to convert it into a list which looks like this:

```
list("a","b","c")
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is a basic `strsplit` problem:

```
x <- "a,b,c"
as.list(strsplit(x, ",")[[1]])
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c"
```

`strsplit` creates a `list` and the `[[1]]` selects the first list item (we only have one, in this case). The result at this point is just a regular character vector, but you want it in a `list`, so you can use `as.list` to get the form you want.

With the same logic you can use `el`:

```
as.list(el(strsplit(x, ",")))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c"
```

Or `scan`:

```
as.list(scan(text = x, what = "", sep = ","))
# Read 3 items
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c"
```

Comment: Perfect. I was trying strsplit(x,",") which was giving me a list of single element which was not what i needed. I have to wait 9 minutes before I can mark your answer as accepted.